# How to flip even and odd elements in a string?

Tags: java, string, indexing, swap

How do I flip every other word of a string?
For example, for simplification, I want to turn:
`"Hello World Hello World Hello World"` into `"World Hello World Hello World Hello"`

I've tried turning into a list, so that it would be easier to access each word, with: `String[] temp = pattern.split(str);`

and trying:

```
int oddInd = 1;
int evenInd = 0;
while (true) {
     while (evenInd < temp.length && temp[evenInd] % 2 == 0)
                evenInd += 2;
     while (oddInd < temp.length && temp[oddInd] % 2 == 1)
                oddInd += 2;
                 
     if (evenInd < temp.length && oddInd < temp.length) {
                int tt = arr[evenInd];
                temp[evenInd] = temp[oddInd];
                temp[oddInd] = tt;
     else
                break;
```

But it doesn't seem to work since I am dealing with strings and not integers. I also tried something simpler such as, but it also doesn't work.

```
for (int i = 1; i < temp.length; i+=2) {
   if(i % 2 == 1) {
       temp[i] = temp[i-1];
            
   } else {
       temp[i] = temp[i+1];
  }
result = temp[i];
```

Comment: for pattern I just used ``` import java.util.regex.Pattern;```

Comment: and str is my string "Hello World Hello World Hello World"

Comment: so it is a `Pattern` , that's ok, but `int tt = arr[evenInd];`?? shouldn't it be `String` instead of `int`; `temp` instead of `arr`?  And the whole loops are somehow strange, why are you testing the content of `temp` (the words) in `temp[evenInd] % 2` ??

Comment: BTW usually you don't need a `Pattern`, just use `split()` from the string (e.g. `text.split(" ")`; not saying it is better)

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the even indices (increase by 2), then you know that every other index is odd:

```
String result = "";
for (int even = 0; even < temp.length; even += 2) {
    int odd = even + 1;
    if (odd < temp.length) {
        result += temp[odd] + " ";
    }
    result += temp[even] + " ";
}
result = result.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try the below approach with the logic as follows:**

***Approach Here:***

*I have spilt the given string via space and then iterate the created array with an index increment by 2 i.e `i+2` and checking whether the `i+1` is out of the range of the array or not. If not, then swapping the values else doing nothing on the array as shown below:*

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello World Hello World Hello World";

        String[] strArray = s.split(" ");//Creating a string array by splitting the given string with space

        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length;i = i+2){//Iterating the string array and increasing the index by 2
            if(i+1 < strArray.length){// checking the value i+1 should be less than length of the array , do nothing if it fails
                //swapping Logic
                String temp1 = strArray[i];
                String temp2 = strArray[i+1];
                strArray[i+1] = temp1;
                strArray[i] = temp2;
                //swapping Logic
            }
        }
        for(String str: strArray){
            System.out.print(str + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Input:: Hello World Hello World Hello World
Output:: World Hello World Hello World Hello

Input:: Hello World Hello World Hello
Output:: World Hello World Hello Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Split then iterate by 2's swapping elements then join:

```
String [] words = str.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i+=2) { 
    String tmp = words[i];
    words[i] = words[i + 1];
    words[j] = tmp;
}
String result = String.join(tmp, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can flip the even-odd sequence using a simple modulus operation in an Intstream of the split String array indices and rejoin..

```
String sample = "Hello World Hello World Hello World";
String[] splits = sample.split("\\s+");
String flipped = IntStream.range(0, splits.length)
                        .map(i -> (i + 1) % 2)
                        .mapToObj(i -> splits[i])
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println("flipped:-> " + flipped);
```

prints

flipped:-> World Hello World Hello World Hello